How do I summon a villager from the desired biome?
How do I summon a villager from the desired biome in the mobile version of Minecraft?

Hi Nadia, what have you tried already?

Welcome to Arqade! Please see our guide on asking Minecraft commands questions, especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far.” Then, [edit] your post and add the requested information.
